# useEffect() in Reactjs version @17.0.1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, use-effect, react-functional-component

I was working on a MERN app. In a component i need to request a api. I used **axios and used it in useEffect** & then i used setState to set state to the response i get from api. But the **state is not updating**.
I saw some youtube tutorials but they are doing the same code & getting the state updated. Is this because of new version of **react @17.0.1** which i am using.

At last how do i solve this problem.....? **need help**.

posts.js file inside react app-

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Posts = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/posts');
    console.log(res.data); // res.data is a array of objects
    setPosts(res.data);  // this is not working...

  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {posts.forEach((post) => {
        <ul>
          <li>{post.username}</li>
          <li>{post.content}</li>
        </ul>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

Comment: The problem is not the setState the problem is that you are trying to render the posts with a forEach. You have to use a map to actually create an array of jsx elements.

Comment: Try first time to console.log the state inside render and told us if you receive data ( delete foreach )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you understand the basic `principle` of using map method here,

Generally speaking `(for each)` doesn't return anything. Meaning that Data from looping the original array won't reusable after the loop

But `map` method return another array

You can read here [Map vs foreach](https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f)

So what you doing now is

```
{posts.forEach((post) => {
        <ul>
          <li>{post.username}</li>
          <li>{post.content}</li>
        </ul>;
      })}
```

This syntax is actually looping the `undefined` . Which will return nothing.

if you wanna loop
you need to use `map` method

```
{posts.map((post) => {
        return  <div>.....</div>;
  })}
```